# Which is correct to say, "How much is the order quantity?" or "What's the order quantity?"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

The textbook says:

> What's the order quantity?
>   What's the price?

Is it also OK to say as follows:

> How much is the order quantity?
>   How much is the price?

Comment: Are these examples from an English textbook?  Or are they from another kind of textbook, such as a textbook about databases?

Answer (score 1):

The original poster's proposed two examples are understandable, but they do not sound natural to my (educated American) ear.  They are literal translations of Spanish sentences, so I would not be surprised to hear someone who is fluent in Spanish use these phrases when they are speaking in English.

Here are two similar sentences that sound natural to me:

> How many items are in the order?
>
> How much does each item cost?

The word "item" can be replaced by a more specific noun, or by a pronoun.

Answer (score -1):

When asking about quantity or price

> how much

is already implied since the answer will be a quantity.

There are any languages which will ask quantity and you would get your second set of questions as a literal translation, but consider

> What's the order quantity?
>   How much is the order?
>   How big is the order?

are all equivalent,

Comment: I'd understand "How much is the order?" to be asking about the total price, not the quantity. And "How big is the order?" could be asking about either price or quantity.